# R - Running functions on multiple pylogenetic trees (multiPhylo objects)

Tags: r, tree, phylogeny

I'd like to run the same function across multiple phylogenies that are stored as a multiPhylo object.

For example, lets say I have multiPhylo of 1,000 trees, and I want to sum the edge/branch lengths in each of these trees. I know for a single tree I can just use:

```
sum(tree$edge.length)
```

But I can't work out how to do this for all the trees in a multiPhylo. I'm sure this is simple, but it's beyond me. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `multiPhylo` is a list (`str(tree)`) and thus provides functionality that `R` uses to handle lists. To sum edge lengths of individual trees, use the `lapply` function.

```
lapply(tree, FUN = function(x) sum(x$edge.length))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a great help.